# can print from command line, but cannot get it from the program

Tags: gdb

I use gdb to debug my program, when I unpack a message and wanna print it, I got a problem. It seems that i can print from command line in the terminal, but when program goes to the `printf("%d has received msg: ", msg->connid);`, I got the problem,

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0xb7ff6301 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2

(gdb)n
154     LSPMessage* msg = lspmessage__unpack(NULL, msg_len, buf);
(gdb) n
156     memcpy(pld, msg->payload.data, msg->payload.len);
(gdb) p msg->payload.data
$1 = (uint8_t *) 0x804c038 "Connectedrt,\031"
(gdb) p msg->connid
$2 = 1
(gdb) p msg->payload.len
$3 = 9
174     printf("%d has received msg: ", msg->connid);  // required field
(gdb) n
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7ff6301 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You did a remarkably poor job of explaining what it is you are actually asking.

I *think* your question is: "how come my printf call crashes?".

There could be several reasons

- You have corrupted `stdout` earlier, or
- `msg->connid` is not `int` (and so it is wrong to `printf` it with `"%d"`, or
- you have corrupted something else in the runtime loader state, and it now crashes while doing lazy PLT symbol resolution

Since you crash is inside the runtime loader, that last cause appears to be most likely. You can confirm this hypothesis by forcing the loader to perform symol resolution non-lazily:

```
(gdb) set env LD_BIND_NOW 1
(gdb) run
```

Did it still crash? If not, run your program under Valgrind, and be sure to fix all the problems it reports.

Comment: Sorry, I really do not know how to describe my problem. Thank you for answering. I'd appreciate it.